# Calculation of a line integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Why does $\displaystyle \int_{p_1}^{p_2} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}dx +\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}dz$ equal $\displaystyle \int_{p_1}^{p_2}\,d\phi$?

Comment: $d\phi$ is by definition what's inside that integral.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Elaborate, please. Are you saying $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}dx +\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}dz = d\phi$?

Comment: Yep. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function most of it is not really *that* rigorous though.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Thanks.